# ASP.NET MVC Filter datetime by weeks

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got a Web API and a Get method, returning a query:

```
var query = from results in context.Table
            where results.Date>= startDate && results.Date <= endDate
            select new 
{ 
Week = { this is where I need a method to group by weeks },
Average = results.Where(x => x.Number).Average()
}

return query.ToList();
```

I want to calculate the average for each 7 days (that being the first week).

Example:

```
Average 1 ... day 7 (Week 1)
Average 2 ... day 14 (Week 2)
```

How can I do that? Being given an interval of datetimes, to filter it by weeks (not week of year)

Comment: Use a [grouping operator] (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea) in combination with `Calendar.GetWeekOfYear`

Comment: I do not want Get Week of year. I've exemplified above. I want a property called Week and for each 7 days, Week ++ and for each Week I wanna calculate the average ( the average being calculated on the Number property for each 7 days the week is formed of ). @Stephen.vakil

Comment: I see.  So you want to take the first date found as day 1 of week 1, or you want day 1 of week 1 to be startDate?

Comment: The day of the first date found is the day 1 of Week 1.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need for the date, but how about the Avg being calculated for each 7 days ? @Vijai

Comment: @Vijai  No, what you are proposing will give a 1 for every Sunday, and a 2 for every Monday, and so on, so All Sundays will be grouped together into a single group, then all Mondays, and so on.

Comment: @Florin I had a problem like this before and I solved it with a method similar to the code below from Blukey_Marcus_Matthews, maybe it will work of you?

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a stored procedure, I think there may be some limitations on your flexibility using Linq because of the idea that normally the GroupBy groups by value (the value of the referenced "thing") so you can group by State, or Age, but I guess you can Group week... (new thought)

Add a property called EndOfWeek and for example, the end of this week is (Sunday let's say) then EndOfWeek = 9.2.16 whereas last week was 8.28.16... etc. then you can easily group but you still have to arrange the data.

I know I didn't answer the question but I hope that I sparked some brain activity in an area that allows you to solve the problem.

--------- UPDATED ----------------

simple solution, loop through your records, foreach record determine the EndOfWeek for that record. After this you will now have a groupable value. Easily group by EndOfWeek. Simple!!!!!!!!!!!! Now, @MikeMcCaughan please tell me how this doesn't work? Is it illogical to extend an object? What are you talking about?

------------ HERE IS THE CODE ----------------

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SandboxConsole
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new Transactions();
        List<Transactions> transactions = t.GetTransactions();

        // Now let's add a Weeks end date so we can determine the average per week
        foreach(var transaction in transactions)
        {
            var transactionDayOfWeek = transaction.TransactionDate;
            int daysUntilEndOfWeek_Sat = ((int)DayOfWeek.Saturday - (int)transactionDayOfWeek.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
            transaction.Newly_Added_Property_To_Group_By_Week_To_Get_Averages = transactionDayOfWeek.AddDays(daysUntilEndOfWeek_Sat).ToShortDateString();
            //Console.WriteLine("{0} {")
        }

        foreach(var weekEnd in transactions.GroupBy(tt => tt.Newly_Added_Property_To_Group_By_Week_To_Get_Averages))
        {
            decimal weekTotal = 0;
            foreach(var trans in weekEnd)
            {
                weekTotal += trans.Amount;
            }

            var weekAverage = weekTotal / 7;
            Console.WriteLine("Week End: {0} - Avg {1}", weekEnd.Key.ToString(), weekAverage.ToString("C"));
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Transactions
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherProp { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Newly_Added_Property_To_Group_By_Week_To_Get_Averages { get; set; }

    public List<Transactions> GetTransactions()
    {
        var results = new List<Transactions>();

        for(var i = 0; i<100; i++)
        {
            results.Add(new Transactions
            {
                Id = i,
                SomeOtherProp = "Customer " + i.ToString(),
                TransactionDate = GetRandomDate(i),
                Amount = GetRandomAmount()
            });
        }

        return results;
    }

    public DateTime GetRandomDate(int i)
    {
        Random gen = new Random();
        DateTime startTime = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1);
        int range = (DateTime.Today - startTime).Days + i;
        return startTime.AddDays(gen.Next(range));
    }
    public int GetRandomAmount()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int amount = rnd.Next(1000, 10000);
        return amount;
    }
}
```

}

------------ OUTPUT ---------------
[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFMfk.png)

Comment: *I know I didn't answer the question*... Then please don't use the Answer Question button. Once you have enough reputation, you can comment on questions.

Comment: I disagree and I think that my answer is good and NOT worthy of your downvote.  Think about what I said.

Comment: Listen, simple solution, loop through your records, foreach record determine the EndOfWeek for that record.  After this you will now have a groupable value.  Easily group by EndOfWeek.  Simple!!!!!!!!!!!! Now, @MikeMcCaughan please tell me how this doesn't work?  Is it illogical to extend an object? What are you talking about?

Comment: Matter of fact, after your response, I built the solution.  See it above.  (15 mins - and yes, it may have a bug but the general problem is solved within 15 mins)

Comment: @Blukey_Marcus_Matthews, We can see the history of the edits you made to the answer. At the time I made the comment you had not answered the question. We have high standards for answers on Stack Overflow, and the answer at that time did not meet them. Review the [tour] and read [answer] for more information.

Comment: Does the answer now meet the requirements?  Here's what I did. (1) Created a class called Transactions, each has a Customer, Date, and Amount. (2) Assume we get entity set from DB. (3) Now, with the business object (Transcation) we add a property called EndOfWeek. (4) We run the result set through a function that gets the Calendar EndOfWeek (whatever day you want Fri, Sat, Sun, etc.) and then calculates the average for that week. This solves the problem. I think, according to the rules of Stack Overflow, I answered the question and deserve the credit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested with tables)

```
var avgResult = context.QuestionaireResults
               .Where(r => (r.DepartureDate >= startDate && r.DepartureDate <= endDate)).ToList()
               .GroupBy( g => (Decimal.Round(g.DepartureDate.Day / 7)+1))
               .Select( g => new
                {
                   Week = g.Key,
                   Avg = g.Average(n => n.Number)
                });
```

Comment: No, grouping by (g.DepartureDate.Day % 7) + 1 will group all Sundays and all Mondays and all Tuesdays and all..., which is very different from grouping by the week.

Comment: And using the datetime's Day property uses the day of the month.  So basically this gives you seven groups, one group with all days 1, 8, 15, 22 and 29 of any month, another group with all the days 2, 9, 16, 23, and 30 of any month, etc

Comment: Still will not work.  Using the division on the month's day, just groups all the first seven days of ANY month together, so you will get five groups only - the first seven days of every month, all grouped together, then the second seven days of every month all grouped together into a second group, etc.  If you update it to get it right, you will end up with my solution (number of days since reference date)/7

Answer (score 0):

You will need to group by the number of days, since a reference date, divided by 7, so

```
.GroupBy(x => Math.Floor(((x.DepartureDate - new DateTime(1980,1,1)).TotalDays + 2) / 7))
```

Subtracting "Jan 1, 1980" from your departure date, gives you a TimeSpan object with the difference between the two dates.  The TotalDays property of that timespan gives you timespan in days.  Adding 2 corrects for the fact that "Jan 1, 1980" was a Tuesday.  Dividing by 7 gives you the number of weeks since then.  Math.Floor rounds it down, so that you get a consistent integer for the week, given any day of the week or portion of days within the week.

You could simplify a little by picking a reference date that is a Sunday (assuming that is your "first day of the week"), so you dont have to add 2 to correct.  Like so:

```
.GroupBy(x => Math.Floor(((x.DepartureDate - new DateTime(1979,12,30)).TotalDays) / 7))
```

If you are sure that your data all falls within a single calendar year, you could maybe use the Calendar.GetWeekOfYear method to figure out the week, but I am not sure it would be any simpler.